# How do I make the Python Interpreter 'forgets' a variable in Cython?

Tags: python, cython, cpython

Say I have this Cython class, like so:

```
cdef class MyClass:
    cdef readonly object _value
    def __cinit__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    cpdef forget_self(self):
        # what should I write here?
```

The desired behaviour in Python should look like so:

```
>>> my_class = MyClass(5)
>>> my_class._value
... 5
>>> my_class.forget_self()
>>> my_class
... # NameError raised here
```

I saw `_Py_ForgetReference` (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/33838fedf7ed6ee907a49d042f8fa123178a1f9c/Objects/object.c#L2226) but it is only activated if `#ifdef Py_TRACE_REFS` is activated.

If raising `NameError` is **NOT** possible, then I would like `MyClass.forget_self()` to set `self`, i.e. an object of `MyClass` to `None`, would `Py_SETREF`(https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/cpython/object.h#L326) suffice?

Comment: You would have to reach back to the calling scope and delete from the namespace. It's a very strange requirement. What are you _actually_ trying to do and what does it have to do with Cython?

Comment: @wim I am actually trying to create a `Secret` wrapper of a `PyObject*` such that once the `Secret` dies, the Python interpreter will 'forget' that the variable existed.

Comment: This sounds like you want a weakref

Comment: Yes, I want it to be such that it is like some of the pandas DataFrame methods with `inplace` keyword argument where the DataFrame is modified inplace by calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Python references don't work like that. Your `forget_self` method only has access to one reference to your object, that reference being `self`, and reassigning or deleting that reference will not reassign or delete other code's references to your object. (Besides, your object might be referenced by tuple cells, or by other code's C local variables. Messing with such references, even if you managed it, could easily crash your interpreter or worse.)